# ShowDialog not render in DetailPage using Prism in xamarin:

Tags: prism

Could you please help me this issue?

I am following this guide (https://xamgirl.com/using-idialogservice-on-prism-in-xamarin-forms/) to implement IDialogService of Prism7.2

It works well on single content page. But when moving link/button show Dialog on Master/DetailPage, It doesn't work anymore. It also call InitializeComponent of xaml Page but not render UI. It also maps success with ViewModel class.

```
public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService) : base(navigationService)
{

    Title = "Master page";
    _dialogService = dialogService;
    ShowDialogCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {
    var param = new DialogParameters();
    param.Add("Message", "I'm a dialog");
    var name =  nameof(ChangePasswordDialog);
    dialogService.ShowDialog(name,param,CloseDialogCallback);
    });
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //  NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(LoginPage)); 

    //Case A:  this nav doesn't work if go masterpage thru login page. 
    // uriPath: /loginpage/menupage/navigationpage/masterpage

    NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MenuPage) + "/" + nameof(NavigationPage) + "/" + nameof(MasterPage));
    //Case B: If set directly this approach. it can work. 
    // UriPath: /menupage/navigationpage/masterpage

}
```

I think something wrongs with path of MasterDetailPage. It works on 3 level (case B) of UriPath and not on 4 level path (case A)

Comment: the code you're providing should work... can you provide a sample so we can see perhaps what you're doing wrong or if there is maybe a bug

Comment: If I navigate to masterpage (mainpage) directly from app.xaml.cs, it works well on masterpage. But when I set loginpage first from app.xaml before go to masterpage. it doesn't work.